# Which wave causes interference in the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, interference

In the classic double slit experiment (not the single photon double slit experiment), an interference pattern emerges on whatever screen is being used. I've always heard this is because light has wave-like properties or because light is a wave.

**Is the interference pattern in the double slit experinent caused by electromagnetic waves interfering or is it caused by probabiltiy waves interfering?**

If it is caused by electromagnetic waves interfering, then is it fair to say that polarizing both slits differently to perform a "which-way" experiment only removes interference because light that is polarized differently

If it is caused by probability waves interfering, then is it fair to say that polarizing both slits differently to perform a "which-way" experiment isn't really measuring which way they went? It is only "setting up" for a measurement. Why does interference go away when polarized differently if this is the case?

Comment: It's a probability wave.

Comment: And polarization is not part of the probability wave function? Huh.

Comment: There is no such thing as a probability wave. There is a QED wave function, but using quantum electrodynamics is total overkill for this experiment since we are _not_ interested in the interaction of the electromagnetic field with matter here. The distinction between single photon and multi-photon interference is completely nonsensical. Photons do not interact with each other because at the energy and energy density of this experiment the em field is perfectly linear. The experiment itself is _not_ a quantum experiment, at all.

Comment: The double slit experiment can be described either classically or with photons, as I show [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269588/is-the-single-slit-experiment-a-practical-example-of-heisenbergs-uncertainty-pr/269596#269596). The two approaches are totally equivalent.

Comment: The conceptual content of the two is identical as well. The place you stumble is where you ask "_which_ way [the photons] went", which is not a well-defined question. It's precisely as meaningless as asking which slit an electromagnetic wave went through -- it's neither one or the other, but rather a superposition of the two.

Comment: The experiment can, by the way, be carried out with surface waves on water.  Which way did the water waves go when they caused a very similar pattern?

Comment: @CuriousOne  It is the one photon at a time double slit experiment that shows that the pattern on the screen can be interpreted as a probability density distribution for photon ( you know, those thingies that leave ONE  point footprint on the screen)

Comment: @anna_v: Please stop spreading this misinformation. You, among all people should know what happens when two photons actually interact: we get _other_ particles with new energies. No such thing has ever been seen on visible light in vacuum and nobody is expecting it to be observed until we have a true gamma-gamma collider machine. Every double slit experiment ever performed with photons is a single photon experiment. At most you are testing the time and spatial resolution of your detector... but that has absolutely nothing to do with photon interactions.

Comment: @CuriousOne: one can put two separate detectors behind the double slit, each measuring the intensity and then look at correlations between the signals from these two detectors. This would be a kind of Hanbury-Brown-Twist experiment, which implies that two photons are involved. I'd be surprised it this has not been done yet.

Comment: @flippiefanus: So when you put two detectors behind the experiment you are getting blue light out of two red photons? Why am I asking that? Because _that_ is what happens when two photons actually interact in the full, non-linear self-interacting theory in second order.

Comment: @CuriousOne: no, interactions are not required.  Go read up on Hanbury-Brown-Twist.

Comment: @flippiefanus: If there are no interactions, then all you are testing is the free propagator of the first order linear theory. That's the only thing an optical experiment can do, right now. There are simply not enough photons in even the highest power ultrashort laser pulse to go beyond that. We are working on gamma-gamma colliders that will be able to do more, but they will, of course, not put any slits in the beam path.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Yes? I think I am missing your point. One can see nontrivial correlations in such two-photon observations even in the absense of interactions. An example is the work done on two-photon speckle.

Comment: @flippiefanus: You are misinterpreting the experiment. There are no photon-photon interactions in those experiments otherwise the photon energies that are going in would be different from those coming out. Please look at the lowest order Feynman diagrams for QED. Yes, there are n-point correlations, but you have those on water waves just as well. Those have nothing to do with quantum mechanics of the electromagnetic field. They exist in any linear theory. You can produce those on simple coupled harmonic oscillators, if you want to.

Comment: @CuriousOne: that's precisely my point. One can do an experiment where one measures the field with two detectors at different locations behind the two slits and look at the correlations (4-point function). The result would be like a HBT experiment, which can be explained in a purely classical context. Having said that, there are cases of such two-photon experiments, without interaction that cannot be explained classically, such as the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect. I think we are getting side-tracted here. So let's end this.

Comment: @flippiefanus: Yes, you can do those experiments all day long, but you won't learn anything from them. The results are already known. I don't know why you think that there has to be a classical explanation for the quantum world. That was never necessary. What is necessary and what does exist since 1929 in ever more complete versions is an explanation how the classical world emerges from the quantum world, that, however, can also not be learned from the double-slit experiment and its variations.

Comment: Now you are putting words in my mouth, I've never said one can have a classical explanation for the quantum world.

Answer (score 2):

Focussing on just the one aspect of the question about the reason why polarization tagging of the slits would remove interference in the ``probability waves'' interpretation:

Firstly, as stated in the comments, one must be careful with this ``probability wave'' interpretation. It is really a probability amplitude and as such it carries all the degrees of freedom including the polarization of the state/field. When the part of the field from the different slits are tagged in terms of their polarization, the interference would go away. Effectively one `traces out' the unobserved degree of freedom, polarization. This really becomes clearer when you do the math. I can add that later, if you want (don't have the time now). Incidently, one can recover the interference with another polarizer behind the screen, if this polarizer selects out a common polarization from both fields.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying framework of the physical world we have studied with our experiments is definitely quantum mechanical. The classical particles and waves emerge from this quantum mechanical level in a mathematically smooth fashion.

If one wants to go to the basic framework for light, one has to use quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanics relies on [postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) imposed on the self consistent mathematical functions in addition to the mathematical axioms, in order to connect measurements to the mathematics. Crucial to QM is the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule)

> > is a law of quantum mechanics which gives the probability that a measurement on a quantum system will yield a given result. It is named after its originator, the physicist Max Born.

It can be shown that [classical electromagnetic waves are built up](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) by a confluence of photons, but this needs the formalism of quantum field theory, which is based on the quantum mechanical postulates . A photon's  wavefunction is derived quantum mechanically by a quantized Maxwell's equation and it should not be surprising that the solutions merge at the classical limit.

Note, a single measurement. In the case of the [double slit single photon](http://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) experiment it is the probability of a point being seen at the screen's (x,y).

[image: single photon ds]

Viewed quantum mechanically that is what the interference pattern is, the distribution of photons builds up a probability density.

> It is only "setting up" for a measurement.

as you say.

> Why does interference go away when polarized differently if this is the case?

In principle this probability density is the solution of the quantum mechanical boundary value problem " photon scattering on two specific slits". As the solutions of quantum mechanical equations are mostly sinusoidal, and sines and cosines when functions are added or subtracted usually show interference patterns, it should not be surprising that when the probability of measurement depends on sinusoidal distributions, interference patterns may appear  or go away , depending on the boundary conditions, in this case the ones imposing polarization.

Comment: Can you show me experimental evidence for a double-slit two-photon experiment?

Comment: @CuriousOne  you are becoming funny in you monomania of "QFT uber alles". Can you show me experimental evidence of  a two electron experiment? You should be the first to know about the HUP and the impossibility of setting up the exact same two particle wave function as initial condition in scatterin.g , which is important in order to be able to analyze the resulting distributions

Comment: All I am asking is that you show me a two-photon double slit experiment. Can I show you a two-electron experiment? Yes, that is what you did at LEP a while ago. I can even show you a many-quark/gluon experiment... it's what LHC scientists are doing when they are colliding lead on lead.

Comment: @CuriousOne no, lep was scattering of one electron on one positron at center of mass, with known energy momentum vector. it is not a two electron experiment . lets stop this here. I have to cook for my family.

Comment: We should talk about this offline... I think you will get my point, one day. Just promise me to think about it a little.